# Is there a power supply that uses a USB port to turn power on or off?

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi3

I am looking for a device (USB power supply or USB power hub) that only supplies power when signal is detected on an input USB. In particular I want to plug this device into my TV (which doesn't supply enough power for my Raspberry pi 3) and when the TV comes on, enable the power supply to power my Raspberry. In this way, when my TV is off, my Raspberry (an it's USB HDD's) will be powered off too. When the TV is on, it enables the power supply to power the Raspberry.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is for programming questions only, so unfortunately we don't do hardware recommendations.

Answer (score -1):

How about a power strip that connects via usb, and when the usb is powered, the power strip turns on the power, i.e.:

[http://www.amazon.com/EcoStrip-1503E-Energy-Protector-Strip/dp/B003CFB9KA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003CFB9KA)